# App crashes using imageView as onClick when pulling images from multiple layout xmls

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-orientation

I am new to android development (I'm a c# asp.net guy) am trying to write an app that is compatible with api10 and up and I am handling the screen orientation with different xmls in an if then else statement.  I have 6 imageView controls in each xml (named imageView1 - imageView6) that are onClick events (I don't like the way imagebutton puts padding on the images).  The reason for this is that I have to change the image sizes based on the orientation so there is a total of 12 images (24 if you include the highlight images).

If I leave both xmls imageViews as imageView1 to imageView6, the app doesn't crash, *but*, I can't handle each of the 12 images independently.  I am only working with 6 of them.  When I change on xml's imageView's to imageView7 to imageView12, the app completely crashes and I have no idea why?  This seems like I am overklooking something extremely simple but I have no idea what it is.  Here's my code:

```
package com.firstmelissa.FirstBaptistMelissa;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

ImageView display1
ImageView display2;
ImageView display3;
ImageView display4;
ImageView display5;
ImageView display6;
ImageView display7;
ImageView display8;
ImageView display9;
ImageView display10;
ImageView display11;
ImageView display12;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_layout, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Display getOrient = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        if (getOrient != null)
        {
            int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;   
            if (orientation == 1) {
                // Portrait
                setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

            display1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            display2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            display3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            ImageView image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            display4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
            ImageView image4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
            display5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
            ImageView image5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
            display6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
            ImageView image6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);

            image1.setOnClickListener(this);
            image2.setOnClickListener(this);
            image3.setOnClickListener(this);
            image4.setOnClickListener(this);
            image5.setOnClickListener(this);
            image6.setOnClickListener(this);

        }
        else if (orientation == 2) {
            // Landscape
            setContentView(R.layout.main_landscape);
            //Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivityland.class);
            //this.startActivity(intent);

            display7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
            ImageView image7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
            display8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
            ImageView image8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
            display9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
            ImageView image9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
            display10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView10);
            ImageView image10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView10);
            display11 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView11);
            ImageView image11 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView11);
            display12 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView12);
            ImageView image12 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView12);


            image7.setOnClickListener(this);
            image8.setOnClickListener(this);
            image9.setOnClickListener(this);
            image10.setOnClickListener(this);
            image11.setOnClickListener(this);
            image12.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
}  
    }

public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.imageView1:
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is Short Notification",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        display1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ignitebuttonh);
        display2.setImageResource(R.drawable.strivebutton);
        display3.setImageResource(R.drawable.adultsbutton);
        display4.setImageResource(R.drawable.marriedsbutton);
        display5.setImageResource(R.drawable.womansbutton);
        display6.setImageResource(R.drawable.sermonbutton);
        break;
    case R.id.imageView2:
        display2.setImageResource(R.drawable.strivebuttonh);
        display1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ignitebutton);
        display3.setImageResource(R.drawable.adultsbutton);
        display4.setImageResource(R.drawable.marriedsbutton);
        display5.setImageResource(R.drawable.womansbutton);
        display6.setImageResource(R.drawable.sermonbutton);
        break;
    case R.id.imageView3:
        display3.setImageResource(R.drawable.adultsbuttonh);
        display2.setImageResource(R.drawable.strivebutton);
        display1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ignitebutton);
        display4.setImageResource(R.drawable.marriedsbutton);
        display5.setImageResource(R.drawable.womansbutton);
        display6.setImageResource(R.drawable.sermonbutton);
        break;
    case R.id.imageView4:
        display4.setImageResource(R.drawable.marriedsbuttonh);
        display3.setImageResource(R.drawable.adultsbutton);
        display2.setImageResource(R.drawable.strivebutton);
        display1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ignitebutton);
        display5.setImageResource(R.drawable.womansbutton);
        display6.setImageResource(R.drawable.sermonbutton);
        break;
    case R.id.imageView5:
        display5.setImageResource(R.drawable.womansbuttonh);
        display4.setImageResource(R.drawable.marriedsbutton);
        display3.setImageResource(R.drawable.adultsbutton);
        display2.setImageResource(R.drawable.strivebutton);
        display1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ignitebutton);
        display6.setImageResource(R.drawable.sermonbutton);
        break;
    case R.id.imageView6:
        display6.setImageResource(R.drawable.sermonbuttonh);
        display5.setImageResource(R.drawable.womansbutton);
        display4.setImageResource(R.drawable.marriedsbutton);
        display3.setImageResource(R.drawable.adultsbutton);
        display2.setImageResource(R.drawable.strivebutton);
        display1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ignitebutton);
    case R.id.imageView7:
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is Short Notification",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        display7.setImageResource(R.drawable.ignitebuttonh);
        display8.setImageResource(R.drawable.strivebutton);
        display9.setImageResource(R.drawable.adultsbutton);
        display10.setImageResource(R.drawable.marriedsbutton);
        display11.setImageResource(R.drawable.womansbutton);
        display12.setImageResource(R.drawable.sermonbutton);
        break;
    case R.id.imageView8:
        display8.setImageResource(R.drawable.strivebuttonh);
        display7.setImageResource(R.drawable.ignitebutton);
        display9.setImageResource(R.drawable.adultsbutton);
        display10.setImageResource(R.drawable.marriedsbutton);
        display11.setImageResource(R.drawable.womansbutton);
        display12.setImageResource(R.drawable.sermonbutton);
        break;
    case R.id.imageView9:
        display9.setImageResource(R.drawable.adultsbuttonh);
        display8.setImageResource(R.drawable.strivebutton);
        display7.setImageResource(R.drawable.ignitebutton);
        display10.setImageResource(R.drawable.marriedsbutton);
        display11.setImageResource(R.drawable.womansbutton);
        display12.setImageResource(R.drawable.sermonbutton);
        break;
    case R.id.imageView10:
        display10.setImageResource(R.drawable.marriedsbuttonh);
        display9.setImageResource(R.drawable.adultsbutton);
        display8.setImageResource(R.drawable.strivebutton);
        display7.setImageResource(R.drawable.ignitebutton);
        display11.setImageResource(R.drawable.womansbutton);
        display12.setImageResource(R.drawable.sermonbutton);
        break;
    case R.id.imageView11:
        display11.setImageResource(R.drawable.womansbuttonh);
        display10.setImageResource(R.drawable.marriedsbutton);
        display9.setImageResource(R.drawable.adultsbutton);
        display8.setImageResource(R.drawable.strivebutton);
        display7.setImageResource(R.drawable.ignitebutton);
        display12.setImageResource(R.drawable.sermonbutton);
        break;
    case R.id.imageView12:
        display12.setImageResource(R.drawable.sermonbuttonh);
        display11.setImageResource(R.drawable.womansbutton);
        display10.setImageResource(R.drawable.marriedsbutton);
        display9.setImageResource(R.drawable.adultsbutton);
        display8.setImageResource(R.drawable.strivebutton);
        display7.setImageResource(R.drawable.ignitebutton);
        break;
    }       
}
```

}

Comment: You could just add a folder in `res` called `layout-land` that would be loaded when you're not in portrait mode. Just saying - it would probably be easier.

Comment: That's the way it's set up now.  I put the landscape graphics in drawable-land and the xml (main_landscape) in layout-land while the portrait xml is in layout-port (main_layout) and the regular graphics in drawable.  If the xml's in both layout-port and layout-land have the same name, I cannot change the theme for each one individually and I'm not sure why...  Seems very odd to me.

Comment: The theme - you mean your app style? If you need to vary your theme/widget styles you can do that using a `land` qualifier on the appropriate res subfolder also. Btw, is the lack of a `break` statement between your case statements for `case R.id.imageView6:` and `case R.id.imageView7:` intentional?

Comment: @JeffMcbride : Your question starts **"App crashes..."** So what have you done to debug it? Where are you logging various stages of execution? Have you checked the logcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *knew* it was something simple! it was the missing break statement between `case R.id.imageView6:` and `case R.id.imageView7:`!  This completely solved my problem, thanks for the help in locating it!